# In Bash, "No such file or directory" when using variable but not when using path directly

Tags: bash, xcodebuild

Context: I'm trying to clean my Xcode workspace and scheme via the command line. I've tried both trimming the quotes and not trimming them.

The current result is: `-bash: ~/my/workspace/location: No such file or directory`. But, if I run the command directly, `$ xcodebuild clean -workspace ~/my/workspace/location -scheme SchemeName`, it works just fine.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
cxc () {
    local path_to_workspace="~/my/workspace/location"
    local scheme="SchemeName"

    if [ ! -z "$1" ]; then
        path_to_workspace="$1"
    fi

    if [ ! -z "$2" ]; then
        scheme="$2"
    fi

    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "No arguments supplied. Using default."
    fi

    # Trim quotes from URL
    path_to_workspace=$("$path_to_workspace" | tr -d \")

    xcodebuild clean -workspace "$path_to_workspace" -scheme "$scheme"
}
```

Comment: `~` is not expanded when expanding a variable. Don't quote it in the variable assignment.

Comment: Use `${HOME}` instead of `~`.

Comment: The quoted assignment to `path_to_workspace` does not undergo tilde expansion like the unquoted argument to the command does. `~` is not the real name of a directory; it's a shell feature.

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub - the error message mentioned in this question (`No such file or directory`) was not due to the use of `~` but because of this subshell call: `$("$path_to_workspace" | tr -d \")` - trying to 'execute' a directory name; while I have no problem with the closing of this question, the reason given for closing the question (`[duplicate]` re: `~ expansion`) is incorrect in this instance

Comment: @markp-fuso Duplicate list edited! this is anyway a duplicate.

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub - still missing the point; this particular error has nothing to do with `~` or `'removing quotes from data'`; error was due to trying to *execute* a path => `path_to_workspace=$(~/my/workspace/location | tr-d '"`)

Answer (score 2):

The line of interest:

```
path_to_workspace=$("$path_to_workspace" | tr -d \")
```

This spawns a subshell that tries to execute `$path_to_workspace`, ie, it tries to execute `~/my/workspace/location`:

```
path_to_workspace=$(~/my/workspace/location | tr -d \")
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And since this is not a valid command ... error message.

What you probably want is:

```
path_to_workspace=$(echo "$path_to_workspace" | tr -d \")
                    ^^^^
```

I'm assuming the `tr -d \"` is looking to remove double quotes from the value stored in `$patch_to_workspace` but, there are no double quotes stored in the variable so ... ??

At this point it seems (to me) that all you need to do is remove this line:

```
path_to_workspace=$("$path_to_workspace" | tr -d \")
```

This should get you past the current error.  I'm not familiar with `xcodebuild` so I can't speak to whether or not you'll receive a new error ...

Comment: Avoid useless pipe: `$(tr -d \" <<<"$path_to_workspace")` or better, avoid useless forks: `path_to_workspace=${path_to_workspace//\"}`

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub sure, agree with your comments but I wasn't trying to address how to feed a value to `tr`, since a) the `tr` isn't needed and b) this has nothing to do with removing (non-existing) qutoes from the value stored in the variable

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the ~. It needed to be updated to ${HOME}. This worked:

```
# Clean Xcode
cxc () {
    local path_to_workspace="${HOME}/my/workspace/location"
    local scheme="SchemeName"

    if [ ! -z "$1" ]; then
        path_to_workspace="$1"
    fi

    if [ ! -z "$2" ]; then
        scheme="$2"
    fi

    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "No arguments supplied. Using default."
    fi

    xcodebuild clean -workspace "$path_to_workspace" -scheme "$scheme"   
}
```

Comment: replacing `~` with `${HOME}` did *not* solve the problem/error mentioned in the question; removing this line of code - `path_to_workspace=$("$path_to_workspace" | tr -d \")` - from your script is what solved the problem/error (see my answer for details); in this answer you've removed that line of code but had you left that line of code in this answer you would've still generated the same error message as in the original question: `-bash: /home/h_and_h/my/workspace/location: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

The tilde part until and including the first slash (examples: `~/` or `user/`) must not be quoted.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

function test_it()
{
    local a

    a="~user/xyz"; echo "$a"
    a=~"user/xyz"; echo "$a"
    a=~user/"xyz"; echo "$a"

    a="~/xyz"; echo "$a"
    a=~"/xyz"; echo "$a"
    a=~/"xyz"; echo "$a"
}

test_it
```

Will for example print:

```
~user/xyz
~user/xyz
/home/user/xyz
~/xyz
~/xyz
/root/xyz
```

`${HOME}/` will only help to replace `~/`, but not to replace `~user/`.